# GCP App Engine Rails application with ruby 3.2 deployment adds argument to foreman start which then fails

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using google cloud build to deploy my rails application. Just recently I upgraded my ruby version to 3.2. I'm using foreman as entrypoint in the app.yaml without arguments and added the runtime_config which I found was necessary for ruby 3.2 (according Google docs).

Here is the code snippet of app.yaml:

```
runtime: ruby

entrypoint: bundle exec foreman start

env: flex

runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
Step #1: Step #2 - "build": === Ruby - Flex Entrypoint (google.ruby.flex-entrypoint@0.9.0) ===
Step #1: Step #2 - "build": Using entrypoint bundle exec foreman start -o 0.0.0.0

Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2024-01-03T08:36:50.619Z16311.wm.1: ERROR: "foreman start" was called with arguments ["-o", "0.0.0.0"]
Step #1: Usage: "foreman start [PROCESS]"
Step #1: 
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Somehow it adds the argument "-o 0.0.0.0" to the foreman start command.

I would not expect the build to add an argument. I tried adding my own argument but resulted in this:

```
Step #1: Step #2 - "build": === Ruby - Flex Entrypoint (google.ruby.flex-entrypoint@0.9.0) ===
Step #1: Step #2 - "build": Using entrypoint bundle exec foreman start -m "web=1,worker=1" -o 0.0.0.0
```

with ruby 2.7 it all works fine:

```
Step #1: Step #1: ## Command to start application.
Step #1: Step #1: CMD exec bundle exec foreman start
```

Why does Google buildpack add this argument and how can I remove it? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was validated here: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/GCP-AE-Rails-with-ruby-3-2-deployment-adds-argument-to-foreman/m-p/694911#M2933

I created an issue at Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319232010